# Export inkscape formatted figure in a separate pdf

Tags: floats, input, preview, inkscape

I am using input of pdf_tex files created by Inkscape as recommended, i.e.

```
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \def\svgwidth{0.5\linewidth}
  \input{name.pdf_tex}
  \caption{Some text.}
  \label{name}
\end{figure}
```

And everything works fine. Now, when all the fonts, equations etc. are correctly in place I need to extract these figures into separate pdf files.

I am aware of `preview` package but I can't figure out how to handle the code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use package `svg` which does all the necessary steps (Inkscape export, including in the document) automatically. With the package `svg-extract` it's possible to extract graphics as pdf or additional to any other format supported by ImageMagick and/or Ghostscript.

```latex
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{svg-extract}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includesvg[width=0.5\linewidth]{test}
  \caption{Some text.}
  \label{name}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `standalone` document class:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% if you are loading any special fonts / fontsizes in your main document repeat this here

\begin{document}

\def\svgwidth{0.5\linewidth}
\input{filename.pdf_tex}

\end{document}
```